# Как можно принять собщение от пользователя Telegram?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, бот

Например, бот отправил сообщение "Введите ваш адрес", пользователь ответил, написав свой адрес. Теперь я должен принять ответ в строковом формате. Так же надо принять ответ пользователя на запрос бота: "Введите свое имя".

Вот это код где Onupdate

```
else if (update.getCallbackQuery().getData().equals("dostavka")){
sendDostavka(update.getCallbackQuery());
}
```

он отправляет в функцию SendDostavka. Вот она сенд доставка

```
public void sendDostavka(CallbackQuery callbackQuery) {
Update update = new Update();

String getType = "Доставка";
try {
execute(new SendMessage().setText(
"Теперь введите куда вести заказ")
.setChatId(callbackQuery.getMessage().getChatId()));
```

Вот здесь он должен принимать адрес:

```
Message message = update.getMessage();
message.getMessageId();
SendMsg(message,"6667");
if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
```

Он должен преобразовать адрес в `String adress`.
Но он даже в `message` ничего не принимает.

```
String adress = update.getMessage().getText();

}
}
} catch(TelegramApiException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

В методе `sendDostavka(CallbackQuery callbackQuery)` вы пишите:

```
Update update = new Update();
```

этим вы создаете новый объект.
А затем у этого нового объекта пытаетесь получить сообщение:
`Message message = update.getMessage();` //message = null